# How to use Jsoup in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, jsoup

I just downloaded Jsoup to use in a program I'm writing in Eclipse. My program uses Seam and I can not figure out how to include the JAR file for Jsoup in my program. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Drop the JAR file in `/WEB-INF/lib` folder of the WAR, or in the `/lib` folder of the EAR. Eclipse will do the remaining necessary magic. Don't fiddle with project's *Build Path* properties or things may go worse.

Answer (score 0):

I did what BalusC recommended above, but I also had to 'refresh' Eclipse in order for the .jar file to be recognized. To refresh, just right-click on the left side window pane within Eclipse and select refresh.

Eclipse Version:

- Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers
- Version: Kepler Service Release 1
- Build id: 20130919-0819

OS: Fedora